# How to draw below dynamic & interactive chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, sapui5

[image]

Below is the industrial plan of a warehouse with all machines and sections there in the ware house . I need to draw an interactive plan as below and all the sections are clickable . For eg: in below image there is a section godown I need to make it clickable so that when user clicks it he/she can see details i.e. it takes to another page of or so. Can anyone let me know if there are any framework that can let me draw a dynamic and interactive plan such as above.All data are from database.

Answer (score 0):

Due to you asking for recommendations, you're only going to get biased answers, but here goes anyway:

I'd personally suggest the powerful [D3JS](https://d3js.org/), as it has a lot of examples, a helpful community and most (if not all) features you are looking for.

Comment: D3JS is built into SAPUI5 btw